# How to delete ingress from default namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

How to delete below given `ingress` from default namespace?

```
# kubectl get ingress
Warning: extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS             ADDRESS      PORTS   AGE
abc-ingress       <none>   app.company.com                80      24h
```

```
kubectl describe ingress jenkins-ingress
Warning: extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
Name:             abc-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host             Path  Backends
  ----             ----  --------
  abc.company.com
                   /   app-svc:80 (<error: endpoints "app-svc" not found>)
Annotations:       <none>
Events:            <none>
```

Tried to delete using below command, But it doesn't work.Please suggest to delete it.

```
# kubectl delete abc-ingress -n default
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "abc-ingress"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Ali Rezvani's answer is correct, I'd like to extend upon it.

`kubectl` commands are structured as follows:

```
kubectl ACTION RESOURCE NAME [ -n NAMEPACE ]
```

Where `ACTION` can be `get`, `delete`, `describe`, etc.

`RESOURCE` can be `deployments`, `service`, `pods`, `ingress` or one of its short forms: `deploy`, `svc`, `po`, or `ing`

`NAME` is the name of the resource(s) you want to apply the ACTION on.

So if you wanted to `delete` the `ingress` named `abc-ingress` in the namespace `default`, you would use:

```
kubectl delete ingress abc-ingress -n default
```

(side note: generally, normally you can omit `-n default` as the `default` namespace is normally, as the name suggests, the default namespace)

Answer (score 1):

If your default namespace for your user defined default in your kube config you can use:

```
kubectl delete ingress abc-ingress
```

but if your default namespace in diffrent, you should pass namespace name:

```
kubectl delete ingress abc-ingress -n default
```

Answer (score -4):

The below command helped to delete ingress from default namespace.

```
kubectl delete --all ingress
ingress.extensions "abc-ingress" deleted
```

Comment: It will be delete all of the ingresses!

Comment: This is a BAD and destructive answer. This will delete all ingresses in the default namespace, and not just the one OP wants to delete.